# Raspbian OS - Android like interface

Tags: android, python, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm dealing with a *Raspberry PI 3* with a specific-made touchscreen, which forces me to stick to *Raspbian OS* as operating system.
I am a seasoned *Android* programmer, and I miss the *Android Studio* development environment and, most importantly, the powerful *Android* graphical user interface. All the basic components of the *Android* interface (panels, sliders, containers, buttons) give a high quality appearance and good user experience.
The *Raspbian* *Python* programming seems to lack most of these cool features. I was able to recreate one of the apps I wrote for *Android*, but the result looks very lame and very 90's style.

My questions are:

- is there any other language than *Python* which I can use to program my *RPI3B* with *Raspbian OS*?
- is there a development tool powerful enough, maybe with pre-compiled libraries which gives and *Android*-like visual result?

PS: I cannot use any other OS than *Raspbian OS*. The display won't work as I have specific drivers which only work on *Raspbian OS*.

Comment: Have you thought about using a web based framework like Framework7?

Comment: @eatmeimadanish nope. I need a standalone system, "locked" for professional use. I really want to build a consumer product around it

Comment: @onik RPI3 model B. Why does that matter?

Comment: I'm afraid, it [isn't working out-of-the-box](https://github.com/pimoroni/hyperpixel/wiki). So if you're not skilled enough, the suggested approach isn't a good fit. However, why don't you try raising up your knowledge in case you have time? By me this is very interesting task :)

Comment: mmmm... it doesn't seem as a feasible path at the moment. It would anyway restrict me towards using the RPI3. The hyperpixel can run on the PI zero aswell. The scarcity of hardware solutions supporting Android Things - which is indeed a great OP - is embarrasing.

Comment: What I meant by web based framework was a gui that was in the browser but run right from the raspberrypi.  There is no difference in security with an app over a browser save for the web based app is easier to deploy, upgrade, and write code for.